# Retrieve content console eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two classes, the first is the server and the second diffuse a video. In the server class, I have a System.out.println before launch the diffusion. I want in the second class to launch the video only if in on console is written "Client" with a certain IP address after.

How can I do this?

Server

```
try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Constants.PORT);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (true) {
        try{
            socket = serverSocket.accept();

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("I/O Error : " + e);
        }

        System.out.println("Client " + socket.getInetAddress() + " connected !");

        new DiffusionThread (socket).start();

    }
```

DiffuseVideo

```
try {

        Util.transfertVideo(
                 new FileInputStream("chrono.flv"),
                 socket.getOutputStream(),
                 socket
                 );
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        System.err.println(this.getId() + ": " + e);
        System.out.println("\n Client " + socket.getInetAddress() +" disconnected !");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I just answer instead of commenting.

But you could just insert some if-clauses to set some boolean to true/false and of course creating the setter/getter for that.

Maybe like this:

```
if (socket.getInetAsdress() == "1.2.3.4") {
connected = true;
}
```

Or whatever. I do not know right know if there are some methods already implented where you can check that and it returns you some boolean. But notice that you must init the boolean - in my case - connected at the beginning and do not forget to set it to false each time you will establish a new connection.

After that you can easily check the boolean in your second class somehow like that:

```
if (Server.getBoolean == true) {
//code to execute
} else {
System.out.println("Connection Error!");
}
```

Or if you use public on that boolean instead of setter/getter:

```
if (connected == true) ...
```

Hope this could help you. Let me know if you need something else.

Comment: I want really retrieve the content of the eclipse console. For exemple if there is "1:cat" in the console, i want to do something with this. For example use "cat" for the link of the video.